# _Setting_ textbox's text using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, findcontrol

I need to be able to set a textbox's (which is inside a gridview row) text to a certain string in runtime. I have used FindControl before, but can't figure out the syntax for actually setting the value of the textbox rather than just getting. Here's what I have, which doesn't compile:

```
((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPath")).Text = dataMap.GetString("targetPath"));
```

I'd be grateful for any help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work?

```
(e.Row.FindControl("txtPath") as TextBox).Text = dataMap.GetString("targetPath");
```

**EDIT:** Actually I like this is better than my orginal post:

```
TextBox txtPath = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPath");

if(txtPath != null) 
    txtPath.Text = dataMap.GetString("targetPath");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't compile is because it looks like you have a extra closing bracket on the end of the GetString() function.

Try this:

```
((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPath")).Text = dataMap.GetString("targetPath");
```

It is best practice to check that the TextBox is not null, but is not required.